# Repeating event and how to avoid

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, delay, jquery-events

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selector').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle('fast');
    });
    $('.selector').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

In work at:

http://jsfiddle.net/Reuben/Au7LA/1/

My code works, but if your not careful you can make a rapid attack of opening an closing panels. So is there a delay or rather what can someone do to prevent this from occurring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selector').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find('> ul').stop().slideToggle('fast');
    });
    $('.selector').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('> ul').stop().slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Au7LA/3

Also probably debouncing plugin will be useful for you http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/docs/files/jquery-ba-throttle-debounce-js.html

---

### UPDATE (Using debounce):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var toggle = function (show) {
        return function () {
            var $el = $(this);
            var isHovered = $el.is(':hover');
            var animation = show && isHovered ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp';
            $el.children('ul').stop()[animation]('fast');
        };
    }
    var mouseenter = $.debounce(400, toggle(true));
    var mouseleave = toggle(false);
    $('.selector')
        .on('mouseenter', mouseenter)
        .on('mouseleave', mouseleave);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/4C6CV/

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. Also how would I use debounce? I'm researching it atm.

Comment: Please take a look to the updated answer - I have added another one example

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('.selector').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('> ul').hide().slideDown('fast');
});
$('.selector').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('> ul').hide().slideUp('fast');
 });
});
```

this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Au7LA/5/